# Html from variable in mako

Tags: html, django-templates, odoo, template-engine, mako

Here is what i want to do, but have trouble figuring out:

I have a variable:

```
${image}
```

Which contains (%s is replaced with image data there):

```
'data:image/png;base64,%s'
```

In mako template, i want to use this variable to provide background image:

```
<div id="watermark" style="background-image: url('${image}'); background-position: bottom left; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

And this, of course, doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work?

Or even, is it possible and how, to take variable and use it to put a piece of html in template, for xample ${myvar} placement in .mako would provide complete div already containing a style with image data?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that this shouldn't work. Try removing the single quotes around ${image} in the url() section of the css.

If that doesn't do it, you can isolate the problem by hard coding the base64 of a dummy image into your css. If that image renders, you know your problem isn't in your css/html.